# Frozen liquid mirror space telescope

Tags: telescopes, freezing

I saw  [Liquid-Mirror Telescopes](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/liquid-mirror-telescopes). With care, a liquid mirror can make a diffraction limited telescope.

The Wikipedia article on [Liquid mirror space telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-mirror_space_telescope) talks about various designs for use in space, including one where the liquid is frozen. This article is a stub with little detail.

Long ago, I read where a large glass mirror was being made from a large slab of glass that was spun for a year as it cooled. The parabolic shape saved grinding time, but did not eliminate it.

I doubt anyone would grind and polish a mirror in space, so it sounds like a liquid can be frozen in space without changing its surface at all. Is this true? Why so?

Comment: A liquid exposed to hard vacuum boils away instantly. If you freeze it first under pressure and then bring it into vacuum, it will still sublimate. Not sure about the sublimation speed, but that's not what you want for high-precision observations to happen to your mirror.

Comment: would mercury sublimate?

Comment: There are a number of problems to solve. A stable liquid is one of them. There are a number of candidates, including Hg. Sublimation is reduced at low temperature. But I was curious about freezing the mirror without distorting it. Is this possible? How does it work? Why is it different in space?

Answer (score 3):

Spinning a liquid in space will not form a parabolic surface the way it does on Earth.  On the Earth, there is a constant vertical acceleration due to gravity.   A liquid surface spun on a vertical axis will indeed then form a parabolic surface.   But in space - or at least in free fall- there is no constant acceleration, so no vertical axis to spin on, so no parabolic surface.

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions 4 designs. One is a spinning pail. A pole has a pail on one end and a counterweight on the other. It spins like a propeller, and simultaneously around theaxis defined by the pole. A second is a continuously accelerating rocket.

Comment: The spin-around-a-rotating-pole-in-space approach *kind of* works, but because centripetal acceleration depends on radius, the curvature of the surface won't really be parabolic.

Comment: Accelerating a rocket continuously and perfectly smoothly while waiting for the liquid to freeze?  I won't say it's impossible, but probably a lot cheaper to build, launch, and deploy a segmented-mirror telescope!

Comment: Ion drives were mentioned for continuously accelerated rockets. I don't know how much thrust you can get that way. They are probably smoother. But waves would be bigger under low acceleration. I don't know if any of these designs are practical or not. But I wouldn't have thought a spinning liquid mirror would be practical either.